# yum install php-mssql transaction error

Tags: centos6

I installed new php version 5.6.15 with remi repo. And now I need to install php-mssql but it conflict with the old files.. Here is the screen of my terminal.
-How cann I remove php5.6.15.remo and all other conflicts file or can I make it other way ?

```
root@user-gwfilter:~/Desktop # yum install php-mssql
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, refresh-packagekit, security
Setting up Install Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: repo.boun.edu.tr
 * extras: repo.boun.edu.tr
 * remi-safe: remi.xpg.com.br
 * updates: mirror.alastyr.com
 * webtatic: uk.repo.webtatic.com
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php56w-mssql.x86_64 0:5.6.14-2.w6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php56w-pdo(x86-64) = 5.6.14-2.w6 for package: php56w-mssql-5.6.14-2.w6.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php56w-pdo.x86_64 0:5.6.14-2.w6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php56w-common(x86-64) = 5.6.14-2.w6 for package: php56w-pdo-5.6.14-2.w6.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php56w-common.x86_64 0:5.6.14-2.w6 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Dependencies Resolved

=============================================================================================================================================================================================================================================
 Package                                                      Arch                                                  Version                                                    Repository                                               Size
=============================================================================================================================================================================================================================================
Installing:
 php56w-mssql                                                 x86_64                                                5.6.14-2.w6                                                webtatic                                                 39 k
Installing for dependencies:
 php56w-common                                                x86_64                                                5.6.14-2.w6                                                webtatic                                                1.2 M
 php56w-pdo                                                   x86_64                                                5.6.14-2.w6                                                webtatic                                                 93 k

Transaction Summary
=============================================================================================================================================================================================================================================
Install       3 Package(s)

Total size: 1.4 M
Installed size: 8.8 M
Is this ok [y/N]: y
Downloading Packages:
Running rpm_check_debug
Running Transaction Test


Transaction Check Error:
  file /usr/lib64/php-zts/modules/json.so from install of php56w-common-5.6.14-2.w6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package php-pecl-jsonc-1.3.8-1.el6.remi.5.6.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/php/modules/json.so from install of php56w-common-5.6.14-2.w6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package php-pecl-jsonc-1.3.8-1.el6.remi.5.6.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/php-zts/modules/zip.so from install of php56w-common-5.6.14-2.w6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package php-pecl-zip-1.12.5-1.el6.remi.5.6.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/php/modules/zip.so from install of php56w-common-5.6.14-2.w6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package php-pecl-zip-1.12.5-1.el6.remi.5.6.x86_64
  file /etc/php.ini from install of php56w-common-5.6.14-2.w6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package php-common-5.6.15-1.el6.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/php-zts/modules/bz2.so from install of php56w-common-5.6.14-2.w6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package php-common-5.6.15-1.el6.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/php/modules/bz2.so from install of php56w-common-5.6.14-2.w6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package php-common-5.6.15-1.el6.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/php-zts/modules/calendar.so from install of php56w-common-5.6.14-2.w6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package php-common-5.6.15-1.el6.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/php/modules/calendar.so from install of php56w-common-5.6.14-2.w6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package php-common-5.6.15-1.el6.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/php-zts/modules/ctype.so from install of php56w-common-5.6.14-2.w6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package php-common-5.6.15-1.el6.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/php/modules/ctype.so from install of php56w-common-5.6.14-2.w6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package php-common-5.6.15-1.el6.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/php-zts/modules/curl.so from install of php56w-common-5.6.14-2.w6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package php-common-5.6.15-1.el6.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/php/modules/curl.so from install of php56w-common-5.6.14-2.w6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package php-common-5.6.15-1.el6.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/php-zts/modules/exif.so from install of php56w-common-5.6.14-2.w6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package php-common-5.6.15-1.el6.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/php/modules/exif.so from install of php56w-common-5.6.14-2.w6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package php-common-5.6.15-1.el6.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/php-zts/modules/fileinfo.so from install of php56w-common-5.6.14-2.w6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package php-common-5.6.15-1.el6.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/php/modules/fileinfo.so from install of php56w-common-5.6.14-2.w6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package php-common-5.6.15-1.el6.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/php-zts/modules/ftp.so from install of php56w-common-5.6.14-2.w6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package php-common-5.6.15-1.el6.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/php/modules/ftp.so from install of php56w-common-5.6.14-2.w6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package php-common-5.6.15-1.el6.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/php-zts/modules/gettext.so from install of php56w-common-5.6.14-2.w6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package php-common-5.6.15-1.el6.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/php/modules/gettext.so from install of php56w-common-5.6.14-2.w6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package php-common-5.6.15-1.el6.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/php-zts/modules/iconv.so from install of php56w-common-5.6.14-2.w6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package php-common-5.6.15-1.el6.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/php/modules/iconv.so from install of php56w-common-5.6.14-2.w6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package php-common-5.6.15-1.el6.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/php-zts/modules/phar.so from install of php56w-common-5.6.14-2.w6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package php-common-5.6.15-1.el6.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/php/modules/phar.so from install of php56w-common-5.6.14-2.w6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package php-common-5.6.15-1.el6.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/php-zts/modules/sockets.so from install of php56w-common-5.6.14-2.w6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package php-common-5.6.15-1.el6.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/php/modules/sockets.so from install of php56w-common-5.6.14-2.w6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package php-common-5.6.15-1.el6.remi.x86_64
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have both webtatic + remi repositories installed: bad idea, and reason of these conflicts.

Notice: EPEL doesn't seems to be installed, you need it.

```
wget https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-6.noarch.rpm
rpm -Uvh epel-release-latest-6.noarch.rpm
```

Then, choose a single provider for your PHP stack.

```
yum-config-manager --enable remi-php56
yum-config-manager --disable webtatic
yum install php-mssql
```

This will permanently enabled the "remi-php56" repository which only provides PHP 5.6 and its extensions (will pull dependencies from remi-safe, epel, base and updates repositories).